# Whats is the standard way to create a matrix of Sympy (symbolic) variables?

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

I was trying to find out the best or the standard way to create a Matrix (or even tensor if you want to go crazy though I dont require that) with Sympy Variables.

I'll describe the only way I've thought of doing it. I found the method `symarray` ([here](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.2/modules/matrices/matrices.html)):

```
A = symarray('a', (3,4))
type(A)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
A
array([[a_0_0, a_0_1, a_0_2, a_0_3],
       [a_1_0, a_1_1, a_1_2, a_1_3],
       [a_2_0, a_2_1, a_2_2, a_2_3]], dtype=object)
```

and I also noticed that one can wrap it with the `Matrix` sympy function:

```
B = Matrix( symarray('b', (3,4)) )
type(B)
<class 'sympy.matrices.dense.MutableDenseMatrix'>
B
Matrix([
[b_0_0, b_0_1, b_0_2, b_0_3],
[b_1_0, b_1_1, b_1_2, b_1_3],
[b_2_0, b_2_1, b_2_2, b_2_3]])
```

is there any one of the two that is the standard way of doing it? Which is the best or the way people usually create matrices with sympy variables?

Answer (score 7):

Your first method is a `numpy` object, the second a `sympy` object.
The difference will be clear when you do (matrix-) multiplication.

First try

```
sympy.pprint(A*A)
```

This will yield a 3x4 matrix with every element squared (element-wise multiplication).

Then try

```
sympy.pprint(B*B)
```

This will not work, because for matrix multiplication you need to have adequate dimensions. So try setting up `B` as a 4x4 matrix and you will get a result (matrix multiplication).

So which one to use depends on your use case. If you want to do real symbolic math, then I recommend sticking to the second method, keeping everything as sympy as possible. If you are more after numbercrunching ("typical usecase for numpy"), probably enhanced with some symbols, then use the first method.

**EDIT**
Looking at the (recent) [documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/expressions.html#block-matrices) I think the most sympy way to create a matrix would be

```
C = sympy.MatrixSymbol('C', 4,4)
sympy.pprint(C)
sympy.pprint(C.as_explicit())
type(C)
```

You will notice that a simple `print` or `sympy.pprint` will not output all elements of the matrix, but rather just the matrix symbol. You will also notice that this method does not rely on the `numpy` package.